# Can't seem to identify data

Tags: r, rvest, tidyverse

I've got this piece of code to try and get the daily spot price for Gold from the Kitco website.

```
library("rvest")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("tibble")
maya <- read_html("http://www.kitco.com/market/")
mara <- html_nodes(maya, "table")
mata <- html_table(mara, fill=TRUE)
mana <- mata[32]
```

I can't seem to identify what the "mana" variable is.  It's not a data frame, and I can't seem to make it into a dataframe by typing

```
mala <- as_data_frame(mana)
```

or even

```
mala <- as_data_frame(mana[1])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `as.data.frame(mana)`?

Comment: You also probably want to reference `mata[32]` as `mata[[32]]` to return it outside of the list.

Comment: So why would as.data.frame(mana) work, but as_data_frame not work?  as.data.frame(mana) works, btw.  Thanks!  Can you post it as the answer so that I can vote it as the answer?

Comment: Thanks, Mako212.  as_data_frame(mata[[32]]) worked perfectly.

Comment: @ReubenMathew Yes, the reason `as_data_frame` didn't work before is that using single brackets `[32]` returns as a list of one data frame. Apparently you can pass a list to `as.data.frame`, but not to `tibble::as_data_frame`

Comment: Mako212, PoGibas, I appreciate your taking the time to help me out.  It's much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
"http://www.kitco.com/market/" %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
    .[32] %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

[image]

`as.data.frame` accepts "any R object" and `as_data.frame` accepts only matrices or data frames. If you prefer tidy approach and `as_data_frame`, you can do this:

```
    ...
    .[[32]] %>%
    as_data_frame()
```

Here we extracted list and now our object class is data frame and we can pipe it to `as_data_frame`